# The proof of the base case in proof by induction must always be to verify the claim is true for the number 1.

Tags: induction

The question asks me to state True or False.

Answer: I prefer True.

I'm I correct?

Comment: Who knows? Some situations start with $n=0$, others with $n=3$.

Comment: I’m afraid not. A proof by induction can start at *any* integer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott More generally, at any integer or ordinal :-).

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Or the base of a well-founded partial order, but it seemed a bit counterproductive to head off in that direction! (Actually, it's quite likely that induction *as the OP has seen it defined so far* does have to be over a tail of the integers.)

Answer (score 1):

Think of the following: Suppose you want to prove for appropriate $n$ that $2^n>n^2$. Would the induction base be to verify for $n=1$? Try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not.

You prove that a(n) implies a(n+1) for n >= N. Then you prove a(n) for 1 <= n <= N.

N can be large. I think I heard of practical cases where N >= 10^16.

Answer (score 0):

No. Suppose some proposition $P(n)$ is true for all integer $n \ge 1$.

Take any integer $a$. Then the proposition $Q(n) := P(n-a)$ is true for all integer $n \ge a + 1$.

A proof by induction for $Q(n)$ would begin with base case $n = a + 1$, which is not necessarily $1$.